# how to join relation Bidirectional ManyToOne SYMFONY

Tags: php, symfony, dql

A relationship between the customer and the order.A customer places several orders bidirectional.
I want to retrieve the orders by a customer,if the name of the customer enters and I see its command

```html
class Client
{
  /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomCl", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nomCl;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Commande", mappedBy="clt", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $coms;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->coms=new ArrayCollection();
    }
//getters and setters
}
```

```html
class Commande
{
  /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numeroC", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $numeroC;
    
    **
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateC", type="date")
     */
    private $dateC;
    
    /**
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client",inversedBy="coms", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cl_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $clt;
 //getters,set
 }
```

Controller:

```html
/**
  * @Route("/clt/com", name="info_clt")
  */

    public function cltAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $motcl=$request->query->get('motcle');//To retrieve the entered custormer `enter code here`name 
        if ($motcl!='') {

             $nomclts=$em->getRepository('SiteTestBundle:Client')->findByNom($motcl);
    //Here I want to retrieve the client id enter And I get his order      
           foreach ($nomclts as $var) {
             $var1[]=$var->getId();
           }

             $comms = $var1->getComms();

             return $this->render('SiteTestBundle:Default:clt.html.twig',array('nomclts'=>$nomclts,'comms'=>$comms));
```

}

View:

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-heading">Information sur le client</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
       <div>
       <label>Nom:</label><br>
        {% for list in nomclts %}     
         {{ list.nom }}<br>
        {%endfor %}
       </div>      
       </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <div class="panel-heading">Listes des commandes</div>
         <div class="panel-body">
          {% for list in comms %}
            {{ list.numero }}<br>
          {%endfor %}
         </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

So,a little search engine, I enter the name customer and I would have his order
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you search the differents order for a customer, do you have the id of this customer ? 

If you have the id,  you can make something like this:

`$listCommande = $repository->findBy(array('clt' => $id));`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I can not get id,you have an idea to retrieve id when I enter the name customer?

Comment: Maybe, you can get the id of the customer by make a findBy in your customer entity. It's strange to make like that because if two people have the same first name and last name you can't find the good one. Try to have the id in this page, i think it's the best way

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I'm not 100% sure if the `@ORM\JoinColumns({})` would work, or if its even needed. Someone else can feel free to correct me but I've never had to use it. To me it should look like this in your entity. I can be 100% wrong, and it's likely that it works for you since Symfony allows so many configurations.

```
 /**
  *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client",inversedBy="coms", cascade={"persist"})
  *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cl_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  private $clt;
```

Provided that you have to 100% match the customers name:

```
/**
 * @Route("/clt/com", name="info_clt")
 */
public function cltAction(Request $request)
{
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $motcl=$request->query->get('motcle');//To retrieve the entered custormer `enter code here`name 
    $nomclts = null;

    if ($motcl!='') {
        $nomclts=$em->getRepository('SiteTestBundle:Client')->findByNom($motcl);
    }

    return $this->render('SiteTestBundle:Default:clt.html.twig',array('nomclts'=>$nomclts));
}
```

And HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Information sur le client</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                <label>Nom:</label><br>
                    {% for list in nomclts %}                   
                        {{ list.nom }}<br>
                    {%endfor %}
                </div>                      
             </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Listes des commandes</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            {% for nom in nomclts %}
                  {% for list in nom.comms %}
                    {{ list.numero }}<br>
                  {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```